# How to allow service interaction through a web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have built an application to host a game server and would like to add a web API for external control.  The application is currently just a console app but will eventually be a windows service.  I've added the web API and am able to respond to requests.  I've also added a TcpServer to the console app and a TcpClient to the web API to allow the web API to send commands to the console app.

However, since the web API is hosted by the same console app that hosts the game server, is there a way I can send commands directly from the web API controller class to the game server host class??  It currently looks something like this (common TCP code abbreviated to save space):

```
public class GameServiceManager
{
    private IDisposable _restApi;
    GameServer _gameServer;

    public void StartService(NameValueCollection appSettings)
    {
        _restApi = WebApp.Start<MyHttpHostController>(url: restApiUrl);
        _gameServer = new GameServer();
        // also starts TCP Server stuff to receive command
    }
}

public class MyHttpHostController
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RestApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}

public class RestApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult resetGameServer()
    {
        // creates TCP Client to send command
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The GameServiceManager is instantiated in the console app and then calls StartService().  In other applications, I've used Events to pass commands back and forth between parent and child classes, but I don't seem to have much control over the web api part of things.

Comment: Can you have your gameServer as static and access it from your web api?

Comment: I don't believe so but I'm not sure.  It has to track a few child processes and maintains synchronization between two other external API's.

Comment: You looked into using named pipes for the communication?

Comment: I have not looked at named pipes.  I had a mentor back in the day that believed TCP was superior to named pipes for some reason, so I've always gone with TCP.  I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't require other components though, but maybe that's not really an option?

Comment: Yeah I would be interested to see that solution. TCP may well be superior, I purely recommend named pipes as I've used them a few times before. Once to communicate between a WPF app and a windows service which isn't too far removed from yours. Though for this problem your idea of using events sounds like a good thing to keep digging into.

Comment: You said that both the web api and the game server class were hosted within the same console app (eventually a windows service).  If this is the case, and all your code is inside the same compiled executable, then I don't think there's any reason to need named pipes, which are intended for communication between separate processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make your GameServiceManager class static, as someone else suggested, you could maybe apply a singleton pattern to it.

```
public class GameServiceManager
{
  public static GameServiceManager Instance { get; protected set; }

  public GameServiceManager()
  {
    if (GameServiceManager.Instance != null)
      throw new Exception("singleton has already been created");

    GameServiceManager.Instance = this;
  }
}
```

Now, anywhere in the rest of your code, you can easily get a reference to your GameServiceManager object by using the static property GameServiceManager.Instance

Comment: Now that's super interesting!  It'll take some time but I'll test it out, thanks!

Comment: Instead of making the instance public I left it private and then created a couple of public static functions that utilize the private instance.  Working great, thanks!

Comment: Well, the "protected set" would have prevented any outside code from ever setting Instance to something else, so I think it probably is the same end result as how you implemented hehe.  Glad that this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I have used SignalR pub and sub which works fine in web interface as well. I already had experience using EventAgregator in Prism and I was looking to implement same in my web api and found [EventAggregator Proxy Signal R](https://andersmalmgren.com/2014/05/27/client-server-event-aggregation-with-signalr/) By [Anders](https://andersmalmgren.com/). Based on above article I done a quick [HelloWorld](https://github.com/skahashmi/HelloWorld/tree/master/SignalREventHelloWorld) Application which may help you out. This pattern can work between web, web api and also windows application.

Here are [code samples](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy) from [Anders](https://andersmalmgren.com/about/)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GenericEvent")]
    public void GenericEvent([FromBody] string text)
    {
        eventAggregator.Publish(new GenericEvent<string>(text));
    }
```